# 3.5 jack mic not working on ubuntu 22.04 pc

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am using ubuntu 22.04, In this computer my voice input device is 3.5mm jack Boya Mic. and my computer detecting it but while recording some voice and using some online cloud meeting platform that time my voice not audible.
I tried my best to solve this issue but i failed to fix it. please tell me the key of method to fix this issue.